# How do you return repeats in a 3d list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, multidimensional-array, jupyter-notebook

I have a crazy 3d list that I would like to return the all repeats or appear frequently in my 3d list but I dont know what code to write.

For example Heres my 3d list below

```
df = [[[10,16,25],[5,12,15],[7,12,25]],[[5,10,17],[15,20],[21,25,30],[10,17]],[[2,7],[4,8,10]],[[16,17,21],[17,32,41],[17,20],[22,24,41]]]
```

I would like my result to be like this

```
df1 = [[[12],[25]],[[10],[17],[[ ]],[[17],[41]]]
```

Comment: Which part are you having a problem with? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: I having trouble on what code to write.

Comment: Invest some time with [the Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) practicing the examples. It will give you an idea of the tools Python offers to help you solve your problem.

Comment: Could you point out what sub-arrays produce your desired output?

Comment: I read the tutorial but it's not really answering what I'm looking for. Is there another way

Comment: @outkast20 Is my answer down below what you are looking for?

Comment: Please close your questions by clicking on tick mark if any of the answers help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given:

```
df = [[[10,16,25],[5,12,15],[7,12,25]],[[5,10,17],[15,20],[21,25,30],[10,17]],[[2,7],[4,8,10]],[[16,17,21],[17,32,41],[17,20],[22,24,41]]]
```

Here is a simple solution:

```
from collections import Counter 

result=[]
for l in df:
    c_outter=Counter()
    for sl in l:
        c_outter+=Counter(sl)

    result.append([[e] for e in c_outter if c_outter[e]>1])

>>> result
[[[25], [12]], [[10], [17]], [], [[17], [41]]]
```

Which *can* be reduced to a more complicated comprehension:

```
>>> [[[k] for k,v in sum((Counter(sl) for sl in l),Counter()).items() if v>1]for l in df]
[[[25], [12]], [[10], [17]], [], [[17], [41]]]
```

Comment: If it is useful and answers the question, please consider [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

Code for finding the most common element in list can be found [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-find-most-frequent-element-in-a-list/). But that doesn't help you if you search for it in nested list like yours, so I created a program to demonstrate a possible solution. It also contains your example list, so you can see the result. Modify it as you wish:

```python
from collections import Counter
from collections.abc import Iterable
import json

def most_common(coll, decider=lambda x: None):
    """
    Returns the most common element in a collection.
    If two or more elements are the most common ones,
    uses passed decider function to decide what to return.
    None is returned if collection is empty or cannot be iterated.

    Args:
        coll (iterable): Collection of elements.
        decider (function(list of tuples (element, frequency)), default: return None):
            Decides stalemates.
    Returns:
        Element type of coll: success
        NoneType: coll has no elements or could not be iterated
    """
    # check if coll can be searched for most common elements
    if len(coll) == 0 or not isinstance(coll, Iterable):
        return None

    # get elements sorted by their frequency in descending order
    elements_frequency = Counter(coll).most_common()

    # get the most common elements (highest and same frequency)
    most_common_elements = [ 
        item for item in elements_frequency if item[1] == elements_frequency[0][1]
    ]

    # if only single most common item exists, return it
    if len(most_common_elements) == 1:
        return most_common_elements[0][0]

    # else use decider function
    return decider(most_common_elements)

def decider_min(elements_frequency):
    """
    Returns the smallest element. Does not look towards the frequency.

    Args:
        elements_frequency (list of tuples (element, frequency))
    """
    return min([item[0] for item in elements_frequency])

def flat_nested(coll):
    """
    Returns single depth iterable.

    For example:
        flat_nested( [ [1, 2, 3], [1, 2] ])
    Output:
        [1, 2, 3, 1, 2]

    Args:
        coll (iterable): Collection of elements with consistent depth distribution.
            This means collections like this:
                [ [1, 2], 2 ]
            Will not work.
    Returns:
        Iterable
    """
    if not isinstance(coll, Iterable):
        return None

    current_level = []

    for item in coll:
        next_level = flat_nested(item)
        if next_level is None:
            break
        current_level.extend(next_level)
    else:
        return current_level
    return coll

class NotIterable:
    # simple class for noting that the function reached final depth
    def __init__(self):
        pass

def recursive_mcn_helper(coll, current_depth, target_depth, decider):
    """
    Recursive helper function for most_common_nested function.
    Should not be called on its own.

    Args:
        coll (iterable)
        current_depth (int)
        target_depth (int):
            Depth level at which the collection is flattened
            and most common element from that depth is returned.
        decider (function(list of tuples (element, frequency)), default: return None):
            Decider function for multiple most common elements.
    Returns:
        NoneType - most_common defaults
        NotIterable - final depth reached, compute most_common from previous level
        Iterable - this depth contained only iterables
        Element type - computed most_common value
    """    
    if not isinstance(coll, Iterable):
        return NotIterable()

    if current_depth == target_depth:
        return most_common(flat_nested(coll), decider)

    current_level = []

    for item in coll:
        next_level = recursive_mcn_helper(item, current_depth + 1, target_depth, decider)
        if isinstance(next_level, NotIterable):
            break
        current_level.append(next_level)
    else:
        return current_level
    return most_common(coll, decider)

def most_common_nested(coll, target_depth=0, decider=lambda x: None):
    """
    Returns list of most common elements computed from elements
    at final depths and target_depth.

    Args:
        coll (iterable)
        target_depth (int):
            Depth level at which the collection is flattened
            and most common element from that depth is returned.
        decider (function(list of tuples (element, frequency)), default: return None):
            Decider function for multiple most common elements.
    Returns:
        NoneType: coll is not an Iterable
        List: success
    """    

    if not isinstance(coll, Iterable):
        return None
    return [recursive_mcn_helper(coll, 0, target_depth, decider)]

list_3d = [
    [
        [10, 16, 25],
        [5, 12, 15],
        [7, 12, 25]
    ],
    [
        [5, 10, 17],
        [15, 20],
        [21, 25, 30],
        [10, 17]
    ],
    [
        [2, 7],
        [4, 8, 10]
    ],
    [
        [16, 17, 21],
        [17, 32, 41],
        [17, 20],
        [22, 24, 31]
    ]
]

def main():
    # called at the start of the program

    # depth 0
    mcn_coll_0 = most_common_nested(list_3d, 0, decider_min)
    # depth 1
    mcn_coll_1 = most_common_nested(list_3d, 1, decider_min)
    # depth 2
    mcn_coll_2 = most_common_nested(list_3d, 2, decider_min)

    # print the collections with nice indentation
    print(f"""Most common at depth 0 (whole collection flattened):
{json.dumps(mcn_coll_0, indent=4)}

Most common at depth 1 (first sub lists):
{json.dumps(mcn_coll_1, indent=4)}

Most common at final depth (last sub lists):
{json.dumps(mcn_coll_2, indent=4)})""")

main()
```

The code includes docstrings if you had difficulty with calling the functions. `main()` method shows how to use it. Don't forget to specify the `depth` otherwise you get most common number in whole list. For example given, it would be `1`. If you want to return different values if two or more elements share the property of being the most common, create new `decider` function and pass it into `most_common_nested` function.

Comment: I appreciate the help. I have edit my question and my result. Hopefully it will get a better understanding.Basically would like to return repeats not what most common. I would like my result to be like this df1 = [[[12],[25]],[[17],[[ ]],[[17],[31]]]